# How to create Chrome extension context submenu items from array of strings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I would like to allow a user to input a string and add it to an array that I would save in localStorage.  Then I would like to add an entry for each of those strings as a right-click context menu item.

I can set and retreive the array of strings fine, there is a textbox on the popup.html that allows entry, and the array is displayed on the popup.html page fine.  They can click a link to remove a string if they wish, that all works fine.  My problem comes when it is time to create the submenu items.  I imagine a for loop solution but I am not sure the way chrome.contextMenus.create works will allow for it.  I look forward to hearing your ideas.  Thanks very much!

```
// Here is an example of how I currently define a parent and three submenu items:

var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": "Comment Replies:", "contexts": contexts });
    var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": "One!", "parentId": parent, "id": "I am number 1!", "contexts": contexts, "onclick": childFunction });
    var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": "Two!", "parentId": parent, "id": "I am number 2!", "contexts": contexts, "onclick": childFunction });
    var child3 = chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": "Three!", "parentId": parent, "id": "I am number 3!", "contexts": contexts, "onclick": childFunction });

// Here is the onclick function:

function childFunction(info, tab) {
  console.log(info, tab);
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { "newValue": info.menuItemId }, handleTheThrownError);
}
```

So I would like to take my array of strings and loop through them to create those menu items.  Similar to something like this:

```
// Get the array from localStorage:

var myStringArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theArray'));

// Loop to generate menu items:

for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++){
        // Get the first word of the string as an idea of something to use 
        var myWords = myStringArray[i].split(" ");
        var myFirstWord = myWords[0];
        var <someUniqueValue> = chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": myFirstWord, "parentId": parent, "id": myStringArray[i], "contexts": contexts, "onclick": childFunction });;
}
```

Is this a doable thing to do?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already know how to create submenus so I don't understand what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: It was the looping part I didn't understand because ... well, I thought they needed to have unique variable names.  I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this one, here's how it ended up looking:

```
var myInputStrings = getArrayInLocalStorage('theArray');

for (var i = 0; i < myInputStrings.length; i++) {
    var myWords = myInputStrings[i].split(" ");
    var myFirstWord = myWords[0];  
    chrome.contextMenus.create({ "title": myFirstWord, "parentId": parent, "id": myInputStrings[i], "contexts": contexts, "onclick": childFunction });
}

function childFunction(info, tab) {
  console.log(info, tab);
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { "newValue": info.menuItemId }, handleTheThrownError);
}

function handleTheThrownError() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log("Whoops.. " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        // No errors, you can use entry
    }
}
```

Thanks!